# Tables with Data Content in Cells as Output

Tags: dataset, output, stata

I have a dataset and would like to create a dofile that creates tables taking in consideration certain aspects of the dataset I would like to highlight.

I don´t need any summary statistics or frequencies but instead the data content itself being present in my tables.

```
* some example data
input ///
str4 a b str11 reptiles
"234" 234 "alligator"
"2135" 2135 "lizard"
"324" 324 "snake"
"122" 122 "croc"
"23w4" 234 "alligator"
"21w35" 2135 "lizard"
"32w4" 324 "snake"
"1212" 122 "croc"
"234" 234 "all3igator"
"21135" 2135 "li3zard"
"3214" 324 "sn33ake"
"1232" 122 "cr3oc"
"2334" 234 "alli3gator"
"21235" 2135 "li3zard"
"3234" 324 "sna3ke"
"1232" 122 "cr3oc"

end
```

Say I would like to create a table like

```
table a b if a=="234" & reptile=="all3igator"
```

What I get has the right format but without the actual content of the dataset (I get a frequency instead)

The goal would be to define my tables in my do file. Let it run through and being able to quickly scan the output for any interesting changes in data after having added new data every once in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you just want to `list` the data.

```
list if a=="234" & reptile=="all3igator"
```

or perhaps simply

```
list b if a=="234" & reptile=="all3igator"
```

since you are restricting `a` and `reptile`.

Comment: If one adds the option ,contents(mean "variable") to the table command what you get is the mean of the variable for certain observations. the thing is if there is only 1 observation the mean is the observation. i tried an other example where my data was in long format with all the observations stored in one column/variable. it worked.

i tried list too but the format did not fit really. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Perhaps it isn't quite clear what you are trying to do. In your original question you said "I don´t need any summary statistics or frequencies but instead the data content itself being present in my tables", which `list` does. If the format of `list` "doesn't fit", perhaps you need to list only a subset of variables, expand your results window, or use one of the `list` options to control the output width.

Answer (score 0):

Like others, I remain unclear about exactly what is desired here, which is defined negatively rather than positively. The example is clear but not especially illuminating: as @Brendan Cox points out, it seems to imply just using `list`. But `groups` (SSC) might help, e.g..

```
. groups a b reptiles

  +--------------------------------------------+
  |    a      b     reptiles   Freq.   Percent |
  |--------------------------------------------|
  | 1212    122         croc       1      6.25 |
  |  122    122         croc       1      6.25 |
  | 1232    122        cr3oc       2     12.50 |
  | 2113   2135      li3zard       1      6.25 |
  | 2123   2135      li3zard       1      6.25 |
  |--------------------------------------------|
  | 2135   2135       lizard       1      6.25 |
  | 21w3   2135       lizard       1      6.25 |
  | 2334    234   alli3gator       1      6.25 |
  |  234    234   all3igator       1      6.25 |
  |  234    234    alligator       1      6.25 |
  |--------------------------------------------|
  | 23w4    234    alligator       1      6.25 |
  | 3214    324      sn33ake       1      6.25 |
  | 3234    324       sna3ke       1      6.25 |
  |  324    324        snake       1      6.25 |
  | 32w4    324        snake       1      6.25 |
  +--------------------------------------------+
```